# Grid doesn't fill parent grid in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mobile, layout, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin forms project
I need that the White Grid fill the aqua Grid.  without relativeLayout it doesn't happens, so, I tried to use relative layout for it but it stills not working....
I have no ideas now...Why does it happen?

how it is now:

[image]

this is My xaml code for this page grid:

```
<RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <!--Picker Grid-->
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="Aqua" x:Name="lojas_grid_picker" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                            Type=RelativeToParent,
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=1,
                                            Constant=0}">


                            <Image Source="pickers.png"
                                   Opacity="0.5"
                       Aspect="Fill"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                            Type=RelativeToParent,
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=1,
                                            Constant=0}"/>

                            <!--left, top, right, bottom-->
                            <!--<StackLayout
                   x:Name="lojas_stack_pickers"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0" 
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                    <StackLayout.Padding>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                             Android="10, 5, 30, 30"
                             iOS="10, 10, 30, 30"/>
                    </StackLayout.Padding>

                    <StackLayout.Spacing>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                             Android="10"
                             iOS="50"/>
                    </StackLayout.Spacing>-->
                            <Grid  BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lojas_stack_pickers" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"

                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint =
                                    "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=X,
                                    Factor=1,
                                    Constant=0}"
                                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint =
                                   "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Y,
                                    Factor=1,
                                    Constant=0}" 

                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                            Type=RelativeToParent,
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=1,
                                            Constant=0}"
                                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                        Type=RelativeToView,
                                        ElementName=lojas_grid_picker,
                                        Property=Height,
                                        Factor=1,
                                        Constant=0}">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Picker Grid.Row="0" x:Name="estadopicker" TextColor="{StaticResource MarromEscuro}" Title="Estado" SelectedIndexChanged="PickerEstado_SelectedindexChanged" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                                <Picker Grid.Row="1" x:Name="cidadepicker" TextColor="{StaticResource MarromEscuro}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding cidadeItems}" Title="Cidade" SelectedIndexChanged="PickerCidade_SelectedindexChanged"/>

                                <Picker Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,20" x:Name="lojapicker" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="{StaticResource MarromEscuro}" Title="Loja" SelectedIndexChanged="PickerLoja_SelectedindexChanged"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <!--</StackLayout>-->

                    </Grid>
                    <!--Picker Grid-->

                    </RelativeLayout>
```

Complete Code:

```
<?xaml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="neoFly_Montana.Views.ProcuraLojasView"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:neoFly_Montana.LayoutScripts"
         Title="Nossas Lojas">

<ContentPage.Content>

    <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

        <Image Source="backgroundlojas.jpg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="Fill"/>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="60">

                <Label Text="Escolha uma loja" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" Margin="0,0,30,0" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White"/>

                <StackLayout Spacing="0">

                    <RelativeLayout 
                                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <!--Picker Grid-->
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="Aqua" x:Name="lojas_grid_picker" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                            Type=RelativeToParent,
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=1,
                                            Constant=0}">


                            <Image Source="pickers.png"
                                   Opacity="0.5"
                       Aspect="Fill"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                            Type=RelativeToParent,
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=1,
                                            Constant=0}"/>

                            <!--left, top, right, bottom-->
                            <!--<StackLayout
                   x:Name="lojas_stack_pickers"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0" 
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                    <StackLayout.Padding>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                             Android="10, 5, 30, 30"
                             iOS="10, 10, 30, 30"/>
                    </StackLayout.Padding>

                    <StackLayout.Spacing>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                             Android="10"
                             iOS="50"/>
                    </StackLayout.Spacing>-->
                            <Grid  BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lojas_stack_pickers" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"

                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint =
                                    "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=X,
                                    Factor=1,
                                    Constant=0}"
                                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint =
                                   "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Y,
                                    Factor=1,
                                    Constant=0}" 

                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                            Type=RelativeToParent,
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=1,
                                            Constant=0}"
                                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                        Type=RelativeToView,
                                        ElementName=lojas_grid_picker,
                                        Property=Height,
                                        Factor=1,
                                        Constant=0}">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Picker Grid.Row="0" x:Name="estadopicker" TextColor="{StaticResource MarromEscuro}" Title="Estado" SelectedIndexChanged="PickerEstado_SelectedindexChanged" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                                <Picker Grid.Row="1" x:Name="cidadepicker" TextColor="{StaticResource MarromEscuro}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding cidadeItems}" Title="Cidade" SelectedIndexChanged="PickerCidade_SelectedindexChanged"/>

                                <Picker Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,20" x:Name="lojapicker" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="{StaticResource MarromEscuro}" Title="Loja" SelectedIndexChanged="PickerLoja_SelectedindexChanged"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <!--</StackLayout>-->

                    </Grid>
                    <!--Picker Grid-->

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <Label x:Name="lbl_ou" Text="ou" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large"/>

                    <!--Loja mais próxima Grid-->
                    <Grid x:Name="loja_prox_btn" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Image Source="lojamaisproximabtn.png"
                   Aspect="Fill"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="BtnOnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"/>
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>

                        <StackLayout 
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Margin="0,30,0,15"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0">
                            <Image Source="reloadicon.png" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

                            <Label Text="Vá para a loja mais próxima" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Micro" FontFamily="Arial" TextColor="{StaticResource MarromEscuro}"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </Grid>
                    <!--Loja mais próxima Grid-->
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>

            <!--Rodapé Grid-->
            <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <Grid
                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint =
  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                         Property=Width,
                         Factor=1,
                         Constant=0}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Image Source="rodape.png"
                   Margin="0,20,0,0"
                   Aspect="Fill"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="FranqueadoOnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>

                    <!--Escrito Rodapé-->
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                   VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Spacing="0"
                   Grid.Column="0">

                        <Image Source="franqButton.png">
                            <Image.Scale>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                 iOS="0.75"
                                        Android="0.75"/>
                            </Image.Scale>
                        </Image>

                        <StackLayout Spacing="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                         Margin="0,0,0,10">

                            <local:MyLabel NamedFontSize="Medium" 
                   FontSizeFactor="0.7" 
                   Text="SEJA UM FRANQUEADO: "
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"/>

                            <local:MyLabel NamedFontSize="Medium" 
                   FontSizeFactor="0.7" Text="montanaexpress.com"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"
                   TextColor="{StaticResource laranjacolor}"/>

                        </StackLayout>

                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </StackLayout>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use a RelativeLayout to achieve this. For what you're seeing, is there any Margin set on the Grid elements, either in the code behind, or in style in the ResourceDictionary or App.xaml?

Comment: I'm sure I don't need, but I don't know what to do anymore...there isn't margin

Comment: what you actually want can you provide screenshot what you expected?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with `erticalOptions` missing a V on the first line?

Comment: no, it is correct in my code...with a "V"